# Android socket.io client

Tags: java, android, socket.io, socket.io-1.0, socket.io-java-client

I'm trying to set up a android socket.io client, but I'm having some difficulties. Right now I'm using this library:https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java and everything is working great when we turn off the middleware. When it's turned on I need to send a header while connecting to the server but as I understand this library doesn't provide such possibility. So can someone propose a different library or share a workaround for this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this library for a while and have found it very adequate. 
If you like to sent header, you may follow sample below;
For version [0.6.0] (previous versions is little bit different)

1 - Create socket.io client

```
        IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();

        socket = IO.socket("http://server_address", opts);
        socket.io().on(Manager.EVENT_TRANSPORT, onTransport);
```

2 - Implement callback handler `onTransport`

```
private Emitter.Listener onTransport = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {

        Transport transport = (Transport)args[0];
        transport.on(Transport.EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) args[0];
                String bearer = "bearer " + session.token;
                headers.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList(bearer));
            }
        }).on(Transport.EVENT_RESPONSE_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
            }
        });
    }
};
```

In example above, I set `Authorization` header but you are free to set whatever you need.